# Display week day in i3 status bar

Tags: i3

I want to display the current week day (e. g. Monday) in the i3 status bar.

My current status bar has the following format:`27.06.2016 18:00:00`.
I want to achieve a format like this: `Monday, 27.06.2016 18:00:00`.

The corresponding config in i3status.conf looks like this:

```
tztime local {
    format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
}
```

I am running i3 on a Debian Linux.

Does anybody have a solution on how to display the week day in the status bar? The man page offers no solution, neither did an internet search...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
tztime local {
    format = "%A, %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
}
```

---

As for the manpage not offering a solution:

From the `i3status` manpage:

> **TzTime**
>
> Outputs the current time in the given timezone. If no timezone is given, local time will be used. See `strftime(3)` for details on the format string.

So looking up `man 3 strftime` you should find

> **`%A`**     The full name of the day of the week according to the current locale.